# Can I edit executed command's informations?

Tags: linux, command

Where does Linux store it's installed packages, that show information in terminal when they are executed?

For example, if I run `ifconfig`, it will display some information (interfaces, and their IP addresses, etc.)

So, can I edit the displayed information? I want to hide some of the output (as I am making a video I wish to share publicly).

Comment: AFAIK They're saved in binaries, no you can't! You should write your own, or find the original source not binary. And yes, if you use `ifconfig` is displays more data than what you need, so you gotta use pipes to make it what suits you!

Comment: Thank you. I thought the same as you said, and the ifconfig was an example,I needed it for another package.

Comment: So in this case, I recommend you use aliases on commands which you use a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just doing a video as you said, you dont need the real ifconfig to show the information.

You can create a text with the false ifconfig output, and create a temporary alias like this:

```
alias ifconfig='cat ifconfig_tutorial_modified_text.txt'
```

Then when you call ifconfig the ifconfig_modified_text will show on the screen so the video will look like real.

When done just do this:

```
unalias ifconfig
```